# HDF5 - Write/append HDF5 Compound Datatype one by one with Hyperslab?

Tags: c++, hdf5

I am trying to write my compound datatype one by one into my file with the C++ API. I am using HDF5-1.8.18 on Win64.

I want to write my compound datatype objects one by one. I have several compound types and they do not come in a "stacked" buffer, they just "arrive" one by one. My code fails when I try to write to the selected Hyperslab.

I want my Hyperslab to select exactly one element of the compound datatype from the dataset at a time. In this test code, I always want to write to index 3. Obviously, I will switch from a static index to a counter variable later on.

My dataspace is one dimensional:

- Rank = 1
- dim = number of data objects (for example: 213)

The code I use to write my data:

```
H5::CompType compType = group->openCompType("tTestData");

H5::DataSpace fspace1 = dataset->getSpace();
hsize_t start[]  = {3};
hsize_t stride[] = {1};
hsize_t count[]  = {1};
hsize_t block[]  = {1};

fspace1.selectHyperslab( H5S_SELECT_SET, count, start, stride, block );
dataset->write(&myTestData, compType, fspace1);
```

The exception that gets thrown is:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.18) thread 0:
  #000: ..\..\hdf5-1.8.18\src\H5Dio.c line 271 in H5Dwrite(): can't prepare for
writing data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Write failed
  #001: ..\..\hdf5-1.8.18\src\H5Dio.c line 352 in H5D__pre_write(): can't write
data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Write failed
  #002: ..\..\hdf5-1.8.18\src\H5Dio.c line 697 in H5D__write(): src and dest dat
a spaces have different sizes
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Bad value
```

How do I need to adjust my Hyperslab to be able to write one compound datatype object at a time? It seems like I would need to adjust the variables that I pass to `selectHyperslab` but I'm not sure which parameters to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this in the meantime:

```
//h5 is a custom Adapter class, which allows me to reuse groups, datasets etc. 
//h5 also keeps track of the count of written data objects in a dataset (used below)  
//These functions are not included in HDF5. Just encapsulate the complexity of the HDF5 lib
H5::Group* group = h5->GetGroupPtr();
H5::CompType compType = group->openCompType("someCompType");    
H5::DataSet* dataset = h5->GetDataSet("someDataSet");


//get dataspace of our dataset
H5::DataSpace fspace1 = dataset->getSpace();

//define a 1x1 (one data row) dataspace
hsize_t dim[] = {1};
H5::DataSpace space( 1, dim );

//get current data offset (index) and set stride, count, block to 1
tInt64 currentCounter = h5->GetDataSetCounter("someDataSet");
hsize_t start[]  = {currentCounter};
hsize_t stride[] = {1};
hsize_t count[]  = {1};
hsize_t block[]  = {1};

//select the 1x1 hyperslab 
fspace1.selectHyperslab( H5S_SELECT_SET, count, start, stride, block );
dataset->write(&data, compType, space, fspace1);

//clean up used resources
fspace1.close();
space.close();
```

See the [Hyperslab documentation](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/select.html) for more information.